# How to check if status is been inactive for 10 consecutive months to send email using MSflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have below fields in my sharepoint list

CandidateName(person field)   status(choice values active,inactive)  Inactivedate

SO my query is how to check for expression if my inactive date is consecutively 10 months in same inactive status then i need to trigger email

Comment: Kindly help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, unfortunately there is no trigger like 'When the value of a column is maintained for a month'.

It would be available when you change item property only change this status value. In this scenario, you could set a condition in your flow:

1. The modified date is greater than 10 months
2. The status value is inactive